# Loading Harmor (and other synths) into Cubase 5

Tags: midi, cubase, vst

I Recently got a copy of Image-Line's Harmor (as well as a bunch of other synths made by the same company), and was hoping to load them into my copy of Cubase 5. I Do know this is possible as I have seen people do it before, but I have no idea where to start.

When I installed Harmor it automatically decided to install right into the VST Plugin folder of my Cubase installation, yet the instrument fails to appear in Cubase. I Can still launch Harmor on its own from my start menu, but have no way of getting sound from it into cubase.

I Have no idea weather this is an actual problem with an install or if I'm just missing something here.

*Cubase 5, Windows 7 Pro x64 bit*

Comment: Any time I add a new VST on Cubase 7 I have to rescan the VST folder (through Cubase): Devices>plugin information>update.

Comment: You can also confirm that your VST is indeed in the correct folder as the folder address is within this menu.

Comment: This is quite the case in that as it turns out any VST by Image-Line gets put into its own folder WITHIN the cubase folder; and the software can't find it. Redirected where Cubase looks and now I have Harmor as a usable VST. Thanks :D

Comment: @BenFranchuk Add that as an answer! It's quite acceptable to answer your own question here, and it helps people who come across it later (like I just did) find out how the problem is solved. The more detail the better (screenshots are great). Good answers collect upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure of adding such plug-ins into a Cubase installation is quite simple- Below is a tutorial on how to do the such.

**Step One-** Open Cubase. For this specific procedure, one does not need open a project.
[image]

**Step Two-** Go up to the "Devices" menu and hit up on it. In the drop-down menu that appears, hit the "Plug-in Information" list item. This will open up a window detailing currently installed plugins.
[image]

**Step Three-** In this next window, hit both the "Update" and "Update Plug-in information" buttons. This will search registered plug-in folders for newly installed VSTs and Plug-ins, and if it finds any, proceed to install them for use in production.
[image]

If it does not find your desired plug-ins, odds are that they are in a different folder than the one that you thought they were. If this is the case, hit the "VST 2x Plug-in Paths" button, between the "Update" buttons. This will open a Select Folder dialog, and you can select the folder where you installed your plug-in or plug-ins.

If this still doesn't solve the problem and your plug-ins still don't install, then likely your plug-ins are either too new for your version of Cubase (Cubase 5 Does not have the capabilities of running VST x3 Plug-ins, for example) or you ended up with a botched install.